# Ml.NET - Pedicting department based on certain properties

Tags: machine-learning, .net-core, ml.net

I'm trying to predict what department should recieve a new ticket whenever a customer writes a support ticket. A support ticket will always consist of:

- `Message`: the actual message of the ticket
- `Subject`: the subject of the ticket
- `Header`: and optional header to further describe the issue

Until now, the assignment of a ticket is manual, but I'm trying to create a model that can predict the department this ticket should be assigned to. My training data contains these three variables as well as the department name

- `Support`
- `Development`
- `...`

My training data consists of 169k rows, and there is no issue training the model at all. I'm getting some pretty neat metrics. The issue comes when I try to predict from some kind of ticket. Instead of getting a department name, I'm getting a decimal (`2.5xx`). I'm not sure where this is going wrong. I've taken inspiration from the following guide from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/github-issue-classification

**Loading training data**

```
var dataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromTextFile<Message>(dataPath, hasHeader: true, allowQuoting: true);
```

**Building and training the model**

```
var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey(inputColumnName: "Name", outputColumnName: "Label") // Department name
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Text.FeaturizeText(inputColumnName: "Message", outputColumnName: "MessageFeaturized"))
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Text.FeaturizeText(inputColumnName: "Subject", outputColumnName: "SubjectFeaturized"))
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Text.FeaturizeText(inputColumnName: "Header", outputColumnName: "HeaderFeaturized"))
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate(
        "Features",
        "MessageFeaturized",
        "SubjectFeaturized",
        "HeaderFeaturized"))
    .AppendCacheCheckpoint(mlContext)
    .Append(mlContext.MulticlassClassification.Trainers.SdcaMaximumEntropy("Label", "Features"))
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapKeyToValue("PredictedLabel"));

var model = pipeline.Fit(dataView);
```

**Predicting department name**

```
var predictionEngine = mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<Message, PredictedDepartment>(model);

var message = new Message()
{
       Message = @"...", // removed for brevity
       Subject = "Other questions",
       Header = "Internet connection"
};

var prediction = predictionEngine.Predict(message);
Console.WriteLine($"Prediction result: {prediction.Name}"); // Department name
```

**Result**

> Prediction result: 2.581

**Models used**

```
class Message
{
    [LoadColumn(2)]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [LoadColumn(0)]
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    [LoadColumn(1)]
    public string Header { get; set; }

    [LoadColumn(3)]
    public string Name { get; set; } // Department name
}

class PredictedDepartment
{
    [ColumnName("PredictedLabel")]
    public string Name { get; set; } // Department name
}
```

Could someone explain me what's happening, and why I'm not getting some string value back, and instead getting some decimal?

Comment: do you have to do what is done here - https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-samples/tree/master/samples/csharp/getting-started/MulticlassClassification_Iris#4-consume-model and de-featurize back into strings?

Comment: it could be your `MapKeyToValue` setup?

Comment: @LewisTaylor But as mentioned, I used another tutorial which doesn't use the method in the sample you provided. So i would expect my setup to work the same way. It could also be the `MapKeyToValue` setup, but I don't know how to set it up correctly. Basically I don't know why I'm getting the result I am, and any explanation towards this could potentially provide a solution in some sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my issue.

It has nothing to do with the my pipeline or the way I train my model. Nor is it an issue with the `MapKeyToValue` method in my pipeline. I simply had an issue with my dataset.

My CSV was comma seperated and used quoting for strings, as my `Message` property was multiline. Instead of trying to support this, I changed my export from my data to remove line breaks, and not quote strings. I also changed to a tab seperator instead of a comma seperator.

The model now seems to work, and I'm getting quite a good prediction.